# Assign selectlist to dynamically created dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have static select list as below

```
var listItems = new SelectListItem[] {
                new SelectListItem(){Text="-- Please Select --",Value=""},
                new SelectListItem(){Text="Death",Value="Death"},
                new SelectListItem(){Text="Resignation",Value="Resignation"},
                new SelectListItem(){Text="Retirement",Value="Retirement"},
                new SelectListItem(){Text="Termination",Value="Termination"},
                new SelectListItem(){Text="Transfer",Value="Transfer"},
            };

            ViewBag.DeletionReason = listItems;
```

and assigning the same to ViewBag.

Now in my page i have to search for a staff ID.

eg: 1234

then in next view all the staffs whose staff id starts with 1234 will be listed. While listing the same against each staff details i need to list the above select list for choose there deletion reason.

I done it as below

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult DeleteRequest(string[] memberIDs,string[] 
deletion_reason, string[] effective_date)
     {
    foreach (string item in memberIDs)
{

  np_user_requests_dtls userRequest = new np_user_requests_dtls();
  staffid = memberIDs[i];
  effectiveDateValue = effective_date[i];
  userRequest.staffid_id = staffid;
  userRequest.deletion_reason = deletion_reason[i];
userRequest.effective_date = Convert.ToDateTime(effectiveDateValue);

try
 {
   db.SaveChanges();

 }
  catch (exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    i++;
                }

            }
```

**View**

```
<table >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
Staff ID
<th>
New Effective End Date
</th>
<th>
Deletion Reason
</th>
<th>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll" value="1" style="width: 25px" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="selectAllInResult"> Or  Select all in result</a>
<span id="span_effective_for_all" style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="effective_date_all" id="effective_date_all" value="" placeholder="Effective End Date All" class="datepicker" style="width: 150px" >&nbsp;<input type="button" name="cancelAll" id="cancelAll" value="Cancel" style="width: 60px" />
</span>
<span id="span_deletion_reason_all" style="display:none">
<select name="deletion_reason_all" id="deletion_reason_all" style="width: 150px">&nbsp;</select><input type="button" name="cancelAll" id="cancelAll" value="Cancel" style="width: 60px" />
</span>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
{
foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staff_id)
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="effective_date[]" id="@("efddate_"+@item.staff_id)"  value="" placeholder="Effective End Date" class="datepicker"></td>
<td>
@Html.DropDownList("deletion_reason[]",(SelectList)@ViewBag.DeletionReason)
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="memberIds[]" id="@item.staff_id" value="@item.staff_id_id" />
</td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Model**

```
public string staff_id { get; set; }
public date effective_date { get; set; }
public string deletion_reason { get; set; }
```

**In the view if the deletion_reason is also same as text type like effective_date I am able to post the data. But I need it to be dropdown.** 
I am stucked there

This is giving me a run time error

```
 There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' 
that has the key 'deletion_reason[]'.
```

Also please give an idea how can i get the value corresponding to each staff while posting.

Comment: `DropDownListFor()` accepts an expression as the first argument (not a `string`). Next you cannot name the property your binding to the same as the model property. Its a bit hard to understand what you trying to do here. What is the method that you will be posting back to?

Comment: @stephenmuecke i'm bit confused here..i edited my question with another dynamic data..which is text..in that they will select the date..at controller im able to get those dynamic dates with the array name..but here i need to show a dropdown im stucked there. i changed to `DropDownList()`

Comment: If you want to pass a string, the use `@Html.DropDownList("deletion_reason[]", ...)` - (not `@Html.DropDownListFor()` but its difficult to see how you post back anything meaningful with this.

Comment: @stephenmuecke my requirement is when dynamic list of staffs are listed need to show a dropdown list against each staff and when post back the corresponding value need to pass to controller..im stucked when this dropdownlist came..im able to do it with a free Text like i mentioned in the `effective_date`

Comment: If you post the model and the controller method your posting to then I can give you an answer

Comment: @stephenmuecke sorry for long post..edited with controller..view and model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can simplify your SelectList creation to

```
ViewBag.DeletionReason = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Death", "Resignation", "Retirement", "Termination", "Transfer" });
```

Note: Do not include the "--Please select--" option. Use the overload of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts `optionLabel` (refer below).

Assuming the model is named `Staff` then the view needs to be

```
@model List<yourAssembly.Staff>
.....
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].staff_id)
  @Html.DisplayForFor(m => m[i].staff_id)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].effective_date, new { @class="datepicker" })
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].deletion_reason, (SelectList)ViewBag.DeletionReason, "-- Please Select --")
}
```

and you POST method needs to be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName(List<Staff> model)
{
}
```

The use of the `for` loop in the view, in conjunction with the strongly typed helpers will ensure you form controls are correctly named with indexers and can be bound to a collection in the POST method.

Side note: The error you have posted in your edit is caused by the value of `ViewBag.DeletionReason` being `null`. Perhaps because you return the view in the POST method but have not reassigned the value of `ViewBag.DeletionReason`?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it's rather hacky, I think what you're trying to do is cast your selectlistitem array as an enumerable and then use it?

```
@Html.DropDownList("deletion_reason", ((SelectListItem[])@ViewBag.DeletionReason).ToList())
```

Comment: Re: Value cannot be null -- Sounds like your ViewBag.DeletionReason isn't in that controller, ensure you have it in your controller and try again

Comment: your answer also helped me..but above one is perfect..upvoted for your help..thanks