# How to save a dynamic dropdown list in MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, database

I have come across a problem. I am currently attempting to make a users page in which some of the dropdowns are variable and determined by their '**access level**'. I then want to save the data from the view into a list and then handle it in the 'Post' controller method. I found this link about a possible solution ([Assign selectlist to dynamically created dropdown in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973923/assign-selectlist-to-dynamically-created-dropdown-in-mvc)) but I am still running into problems.

Here is my controller code I am using to set up the data that needs to generate the dropdowns:

```
var permData = db.LabPermissions.Where(x => x.AccessLevel == 1).ToList();    

  //sets up generic dropdown data used for all dropdowns
  ViewBag.DropDownData = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
         new SelectListItem{ Value = "0",Text = "No"},
         new SelectListItem{ Value = "1",Text = "Yes"},
   };

   ViewModel obj = new ViewModel();
   obj.DataFromController = permData;
   //other viewmodel data
   return("MyView",obj);
```

I then pass the data to my view which looks like this (this is also how the stack overflow link set up the view)

```
  @for(int i = 0; i < Model.DataFromController.Count(); i++)
        {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DataFromController[i].Lab.LabName)</b> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DataFromController[i].Assigner, (SelectList)ViewBag.DropDownData, "Select One")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
        </div>
        }
```

After I get this set up, and run the application, this is the error I receive:

```
 Additional information: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'
```

And the error is placed on my @Html.DropDownListFor line of code in my view.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `ViewBag.DropDownData` is typeof `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not `SelectList` so trying to cast it as you have done with `(SelectList)ViewBag.DropDownData` throws the exception - it would need to be `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownData`. Note that `SelectList` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, but `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is not `SelectList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new selectlist instead and put your selectlistitems in it.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DataFromController[i].Assigner, 
new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDownData, "Value", "Text", "Select One")
```

Or, since you got a `ViewModel` you can add a public property that can hold your selectlistitems.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownData { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var permData = db.LabPermissions.Where(x => x.AccessLevel == 1).ToList();
var vm = new ViewModel();

var list = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{ Value = "-1", Text = "Select One", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem{ Value = "0",Text = "No"},
            new SelectListItem{ Value = "1",Text = "Yes"}
        };
vm.DropDownData = list;
vm.DataFromController = permData;
return View(vm);
```

View:

```
@model YourNameSpace.Models.ViewModel


@for(int i = 0; i < Model.DataFromController.Count(); i++){

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DataFromController[i].Assigner, Model.DropDownData)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, much easier solution!

Comment: Great @Eli Hellmer, happy to help.

Comment: The first example will work, but the second wont (it will not select the correct option based on the value of property `Assigner`. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909070/html-dropdownlistfor-default-selected-value-in-mvc5/30911222#30911222) for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're trying to cast SelectListItem to SelectList and that is the reason why you're getting that error. I've done the same feature as a part of my project and I'm taking the values for the dropdownlist from the database.
and for displaying, here is my code(modified a bit based on your model variables

My Controller method

```
public ActionResult GetDropDownList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> dropDownList= new List<SelectListItem>();
            using (var context = new assessmentEntities())
            {
                 //getting data from the DB
               var result = context.getDataFromDB().toList();

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    dropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Variable1, Value = item.Variable2});
                }
                ViewBag.DropDownData = dropDownList;
            }
    return View();
        }`
```

Here is my View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DataFromController[i].Assigner,, new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDownData, "Value", "Text")
```

Hope so this works for you